# What's needed in a C++ binary tree class

Tags: c++, tree, binary-tree

I've mostly programmed in C. If I make a binary tree class in C++, do I need to include a pointer to the root as a property so I can delete each node in the destructor or is it usually done another way? And do I need a constructor?

Other than that, I just have data, left, right, and the methods, correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I've mostly programmed in C. If I make a binary tree class in C++, do
>   I need to include a pointer to the root as a property so I can delete
>   each node in the destructor or is it usually done another way?

You'll want to be able to clean up after nodes if you allocate memory for them or you'll have leaks.

> And do I need a constructor?

I'd recommend the four horsemen of the apocolypse: constructor, destructor, copy constructor, and assignment operator.

> Other than that, I just have data, left, right, and the methods,
>   correct?

I'd follow the example of the STL and create iterators: depth first, breadth first, etc.

Answer (score 4):

Normally C++ objects aren't designed to be able to delete themselves out of a container. Instead, the *container* (in this case your binary tree) is considered the owner of the object. The destructor would be called when the container decides to delete the node (presumably based on some request by your code).

Having a pointer to a binary tree root would violate encapsulation. Ideally, you would want your object to be able to be inserted into some other container such as a vector, too. For example, the standard type `std::string` has no idea what it might be inserted into. Its destructor is only responsible for cleaning things up inside itself.

Answer (score 0):

Creating a pointer to the root node is usually necessary if you want it done properly. It's easier that way as well if you want to denote 'null' root as an empty tree.

Most objects should have constructors, in this case a decent use of the constructor could be another binary search tree (to copy it).